# CKEDITOR disallowedContent doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to let my user can use the 'source' of ckeditor for being to insert html but I want to disallow some tags for avoiding xss attack

I'm trying to disallow script tag for example like this in my `config.js`

```
config.allowedContent = {
    $1: {
        elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
        attributes: true,
        styles: true,
        classes: true
    }
};
config.disallowedContent = 'script;';
```

But it doesn't work I can keep using `<script/>` tags

I also did

```
config.disallowedContent = 'script;';
```

Doesn't work either.

I'm using CKEDITOR 4.11.1 and Rails 5.x.

Comment: From what I have checked the code above works. When I paste HTML with script tags into CKEditor source mode and then switch to WYSIWYG and again to Source, the script tags are gone. How exactly are you inserting them into editor? NOTE: it should not matter but just in case I would not use semicolon at the end `config.disallowedContent = 'script';`

Comment: I go on source mode then past `<script>alert('test')</script>` and submit my message then when I arrive on the post page the script alert is executed

Comment: I don't know exactly why but after restarted my rails server it worked. I thought it wouldn't need it because the config.js would be executed every time the page is loaded.

Comment: It should. Maybe that file got cached for some reason and that is why you were using an old version. TIP: You can also use editor configuration directly on HTML page which should definitely get loaded when page loads: `var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {allowedContent : { $1: {elements: CKEDITOR.dtd, attributes: true,styles: true,classes: true}}, disallowedContent : 'script;'});` The difference between this method and `config.js` is that it will work only on a single editor instance and not all of them.